# Renaming Files With Batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, directory

I am new completely new to batch and have used Python, Java ect for about a year now. So as you can guess I dont know overly large amount.

I have been instructed by my employer to try and automate some tasks we do on a regular basis. This may sound like a stupid task that is easy to-do but it happens a lot and when talking to customers at the same time it get boring quick. The task: Renaming multiple folders... We do this when end users have forgotten their password or need a profile reset.

The code that I have at the moment is:

```
:again 
@echo off
   set /p answer= Rename a file/folder(Y/N)?
   if /i "%answer:~,1%" EQU "Y" goto yes
   if /i "%answer:~,1%" EQU "N" goto no
   goto again

:yes
  set /p dirOfFile = Directory of file:
  set /p currentFolder = Name of folder to be re-named:
  set /p newFolder = What will it be re-named to:

  ren %dirOfFile%\%currentFolder% %newFolder%

:no
  exit
```

The code is based off of a few sources, the Y/N and using variable from other StackOverflow posts and the `ren %dirOfFile%\%currentFolder% %newFolder%` from the cmd command of `ren` or `rename`. 
When I use:

```
ren C:\Users\Zak\Desktop\TestFolder AlsoTest
```

It renames a folder on my desktop from TestFolder to AlsoTest. This is what I want the batch file todo, but once its working, on multiple folders.

Thanks for any/all help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't have a parameter `%dirOfFile%`. But you have a parameter named `%dirOfFile<space>%`

Same with you other variables.

Write your `set`command without spaces:

```
set variable=value
```

for example:

```
set /p dirOfFile=Directory of file:
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple You can rename any File with Batch

type the following in batch file

ren "oldfile.txt" "newfile.txt"